# How to add a widget zone in MVC view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My site is running on nopcommerce 4.1. I'd like to add a widget, but only to show on specific category. I've successfully added one widget, but how to add another one similar to below:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Widget", new { widgetZone = "example", additionalData = Model.Id })
@{
  var categoryIds = new List<int> { 109, 179 }; // list wanna show categories here, inside bracket with IDs
  if (categoryIds.Contains(Model.Id))
  {
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("Widget", new { widgetZone = "example", additionalData = Model.Id })
  }
}
```

How to add another widget, let's say

```
  @await Component.InvokeAsync("Widget", new { widgetZone = "example2", additionalData = Model.Id })
```

Answer (score 0):

WidgetZones are included in NopCommerce as a flexible and modular way to add widgets / viewcomponents to your pages. If you look up the NopCommerce sourcecode and find the `Nop.Services.Cms.WidgetService` class, you can see how this works.

In short, widgets are loaded by finding all classes that implement `IWidgetPlugin`, selecting the widgets that are active and selecting the widgets for the current widget zone. Widgets can state the widget zones they want to render in, in their `GetWidgetZones()` method (which is a member of the `IWidgetPlugin` interface).

So, it should be perfectly possible for you to create your own widget zone, use some conditional logic in your razor page to check for certain conditions (i.e. if `Model.Id` matches some category Id) and invoke the `InvokeAsync` method of any widgets that defined in their `GetWidgetZones()` method that they want to render in your widget zone.

To build on your example, in your plugin class (the one inheriting from `BasePlugin` and implementing `IWidgetPlugin` you should include:

```
public IList<string> GetWidgetZones() {
    return new List<string>{
        "example2"
    }
}
```

And then in your Razor Page you can do:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Widget", new { widgetZone = "example", additionalData = Model.Id })
@{
  var categoryIds = new List<int> { 109, 179 }; // list wanna show categories here, inside bracket with IDs
  if (categoryIds.Contains(Model.Id))
  {
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("Widget", new { widgetZone = "example", additionalData = Model.Id })
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("Widget", new { widgetZone = "example2", additionalData = Model.Id })
  }
}
```